# Operators == and === on objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know very well the difference b/w the 2 operators in context to ***primitive types (number, string, boolean, null and undefined)***. I mean all that stuff,

```
0 == false   // true
0 === false  // false, because they are of a different type
1 == "1"     // true, auto type coercion
1 === "1"    // false, because they are of a different type
null == undefined // true
null === undefined // false
'0' == false // true
'0' === false // false
```

Consider the snippet,

```
        var str3 = new String("abc");
        var str4 = new String("abc");

        // false as 2 different objects, referential equality just like in java
        alert(str3 == str4);


        var str5 = new String("abc");
        var str6 = str5;
        alert(str6 == str5);        // true, as pointing to the same object
```

For ***str5*** and ***str6***, they will compare truthfully. Use of the strict comparison ***(===)*** will, of course, produce the ***same result***, as they are the ***same value and type***; indeed, they are the ***same object***!

Now consider,

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

// the function person has a prototype property
// we can add properties to this function prototype
Person.prototype.kind = ‘person’

// when we create a new object using new
var zack = new Person(‘Zack’);

// the prototype of the new object points to person.prototype
zack.__proto__ == Person.prototype //=> true

zack.__proto__ === Person.prototype //=> false
```

I find myself really confused with the last 2 lines:

```
zack.__proto__ == Person.prototype //=> true
zack.__proto__ === Person.prototype //=> false
```

As per my understanding  `zack.__proto__` and `Person.prototype` are pointing to the ***same object (same location in memory)***, hence ***true***.

If so, why `zack.__proto__ === Person.prototype` ***false*** then, as the type of both ***zack.__proto__*** and *Person.prototype* is ***object*** and since they are pointing to the ***same location in memory***, ***they must have equal values***.

Comment: Where is `Foo` defined?

Comment: @elclanrs : So Sorry everyone. Edited.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari You should use `'` or `"` instead of `‘`.

Comment: I can't reproduce you problem. I get `true`, as expected.

Comment: @Oriol: I got false in Eclipse IDE and true in Google Chrome.

Comment: The `__proto__` property is [*non–standard and deprecated*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), so you shouldn't be using it anyway. Try [*Object.getPrototypeOf*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.2) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both operands have the same type, it doesn't matter if you use `==` or `===`:

> **[11.9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm**
>
> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or
>   false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
>
>    1. If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.
>    2. If Type(x) is Null, return true.
>    3. If Type(x) is Number, then
>
>       1. If x is NaN, return false.
>       2. If y is NaN, return false.
>       3. If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
>       4. If x is +0 and y is −0, return true.
>       5. If x is −0 and y is +0, return true.
>       6. Return false.
>    4. If Type(x) is String, then return true if x and y are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in
>         corresponding positions). Otherwise, return false.
>    5. If Type(x) is Boolean, return true if x and y are both true or both false. Otherwise, return false.
>    6. Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.
> 2. [...]
>
> **[11.9.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm**
>
> The comparison x === y, where x and y are values, produces true or
>   false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.
> 2. If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.
> 3. If Type(x) is Null, return true.
> 4. If Type(x) is Number, then
>
>    1. If x is NaN, return false.
>    2. If y is NaN, return false.
>    3. If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
>    4. If x is +0 and y is −0, return true.
>    5. If x is −0 and y is +0, return true.
>    6. Return false.
> 5. If Type(x) is String, then return true if x and y are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in
>      corresponding positions); otherwise, return false.
> 6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return true if x and y are both true or both false; otherwise, return false.
> 7. Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.

Therefore,

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.kind = 'person';
var zack = new Person('Zack');
zack.__proto__ == Person.prototype;  // true
zack.__proto__ === Person.prototype; // true
```

If you say it returns `false` in Eclipse IDE, it means Eclipse IDE doesn't follow ECMAScript standard.

Comment: When you said true reflects in both situations, I then cross checked with Google Chrome. And thank you very much.